# How do I get the SHA associated with the actual code for a tag?

Tags: github, github-api

I would like to get the SHA for the actual code associated with a tag.  Is this possible?  What seems to be available from the API is a SHA for the creation of the tag, which for my purposes is much less helpful.

If I visit

```
https://github.com/:owner/:repo/releases/tag/:tag
https://github.com/ramda/ramda/releases/tag/v0.12.0
```

I can find in `.tag-references li:eq(1) a` a link to the latest commit that was used to build the tag.  (Or I assume that's what it is.)  It's in the form

```
https://github.com/:owner/:repo/commit/:sha
https://github.com/ramda/ramda/commit/e2fad9bc6dd425a00dd98d2fb7ab1a9c52fce074
```

I **could** extract this SHA and use it to build links from my documentation to the source files (which is what this is all about.)  But that involves screen-scraping.  I would much prefer to use the API.

But the API, as far as I can tell, gives me a list of tags through the following call:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/git/refs/tags
https://api.github.com/repos/ramda/ramda/git/refs/tags
```

that includes an entry like this:

```
{
  "ref": "refs/tags/v0.12.0",
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/ramda/ramda/git/refs/tags/v0.12.0",
  "object": {
    "sha": "c71639093b1a433fa68d4df2056be32a635a56d5",
    "type": "tag",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/ramda/ramda/git/tags/c71639093b1a433fa68d4df2056be32a635a56d5"
  }
}
```

While I have no issues parsing the response to find the correct entry, the resulting SHA seems to have nothing to do with the code that I want to make reference to.

Is there some way through the API to find the SHA that's displayed on the tag page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go to the URL for the tag object (https://api.github.com/repos/ramda/ramda/git/tags/c71639093b1a433fa68d4df2056be32a635a56d5) Included in the json response for the tag ref, you get:

```
{
  "sha": "c71639093b1a433fa68d4df2056be32a635a56d5",
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/ramda/ramda/git/tags/c71639093b1a433fa68d4df2056be32a635a56d5",
  "tagger": {
    "name": "buzzdecafe",
    "email": "m_hur@yahoo.com",
    "date": "2015-03-21T22:25:46Z"
  },
  "object": {
    "sha": "e2fad9bc6dd425a00dd98d2fb7ab1a9c52fce074",
    "type": "commit",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/ramda/ramda/git/commits/e2fad9bc6dd425a00dd98d2fb7ab1a9c52fce074"
  },
  "tag": "v0.12.0",
  "message": "Version 0.12.0\n"
}
```

Which has the SHA1 of the commit object you're looking for (`e2fad9bc6dd425a00dd98d2fb7ab1a9c52fce074`) as `object.sha`

Git actually has two kinds of tags: lightweight tags and annotated tags. The lightweight ones are just refs that point directly to the commit sha. An annotated tag is actually an object with its own sha, which has a pointer to the commit sha. This is an example of the second kind of tag. (See `man git-tag` for a bit more detail)

Comment: D'oh.  I swear I did that once and that the only SHA I saw was the original.  I must be going blind!  Thanks.